# 500 error when copying a google spreadsheet

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I'm trying to copy a google spreadsheet using the [google_drive](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) gem. This has been working for many months before.

However, I'm now getting the following error consistently:

`Sending HTTP post https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$fileid/copy?fields=%2A`

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "responsePreparationFailure",
    "message": "The operation was successful, but there was an error preparing the response."
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "The operation was successful, but there was an error preparing the response."
 }
}
```

I've tried updating the library, but with no joy. The docs for the [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/copy) don't mention this `fields` parameter. Could this be the issue?

Comment: This is definitely the problem on their side, and you should just wait a bit until Google has it fixed. Gem and your code most likely work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

500 is a Google server issue.  Your best with these is to wait a few minutes and try again.   you can also check their server status page to make sure there is nothing down

https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=da&v=status